# Gson conversion to a Java Pojo make values null

Tags: java, json, gson, postman

I have to persist a POJO class Community in a db using hibernate. I have this method in the class ManageCommunity:

```
public void persistCommunity(String name,String domain,String idCustomer){
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        Community aCommunity=new Community();
        aCommunity.setName(name);
        aCommunity.setDomain(domain);
        aCommunity.setIdCustomer(idCustomer);
       // aCommunity.setIdCommunity(aCommunity.getIdCommunity());
        session.save(aCommunity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }
```

On the servlet with doPost i call this method and i pass the parameter of json send by postman:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    Gson g = new Gson();
    System.out.println(CommunityHome.getBody(req));
    Community community = g.fromJson(CommunityHome.getBody(req), Community.class);
    System.out.println("Community: "+community);

    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    try {
        ManageCommunity manageCommunity = new ManageCommunity();
        manageCommunity.persistCommunity(community.getName(),community.getDomain(),community.getIdCustomer());

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now value of community is null, but if i see getBody(req) there is the json

This is getBody:

```
private static String getBody(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {

        String body = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                    stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append("");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } /*finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }*/

        body = stringBuilder.toString();
        return body;
    }
```

This is POJO class:

```
public class Community{
    public Community(){
        UUID uuid=UUID.randomUUID();
        String random=uuid.toString();
        this.idCommunity=random;
    }



    public String getIdCommunity() {
        return idCommunity;
    }
    public void setIdCommunity(String idCommunity) {
        this.idCommunity = idCommunity;
    }
    public String getIdCustomer() {
        return idCustomer;
    }
    public void setIdCustomer(String idCustomer) {
        this.idCustomer = idCustomer;
    }
    public String getDomain() {
        return domain;
    }
    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String idCommunity;
    private String idCustomer;
    private String domain;
    private String name;

}
```

The content of `CommunityHome.getBody(req)` is:

`{"idCustomer":"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668", "name":"VenditaAbiti2", "domain":"Commerce2"}`

Comment: Your json is incorrect. Right now the root level is not Community like you want it to be.

Comment: i have validate online it is correct..where is the error for you?

Comment: Your question is not clear,Please make your post more clearer

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo the syntax was right, but the root level was wrong. It means that your JSON expects a Object with the Community field inside it, not simply idCostumer, etc.

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo what do you get System.out.println(CommunityHome.getBody(req));

Comment: { "idCustomer":"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668", "name":"VenditaAbiti2", "domain":"Commerce2" }

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo can you show me your community pojo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your json to this:

```
{"IdCustomer":"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668",
   "Name":"VenditaAbiti2",
   "Domain":"Commerce2"
}
```

Got it working in this small example:

```
String json = "{\"IdCustomer\":\"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668\",\"Name\":\"VenditaAbiti2\",\"Domain\":\"Commerce2\"}";
        Gson g = new Gson();
        Community community = g.fromJson(json, Community.class);
        System.out.println("Community:" + community.toString());

    }

    class Community {
    @SerializedName("IdCustomer")
    private String idCustomer;

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Domain")
    private String domain;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Community [idCustomer=" + idCustomer + ", name=" + name + ", domain=" + domain + "]";
    }

//getter setter
```

Output: `Community:Community [IdCustomer=bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668, Name=VenditaAbiti2, Domain=Commerce2]`

---

**EDIT1:**

Your Pojo variable names should match with the key names of your json String. Means The json key `"IdCustomer"` starts with an uppercase. Your variable starts with a lower case. This cannot match. 
But you are able to **annotate** your variables like in my answer. There you can give the **explicit name of the json key**.

Comment: Probably something to do with the json starting uppercase and the fields lowercase.

Comment: in getBody i receive the json but in community goes always null

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo provide the content of `CommunityHome.getBody(req)`

Comment: {  "idCustomer":"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668",
"name":"VenditaAbiti2",
"domain":"Commerce2"
}

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo if this is the result of `CommunityHome.getBody(req)` your gson should work without problems.  Can you also show your Community Class.

Comment: @Patrick   
yes it is the result of that method. I have added pojo

Comment: @Patrick i have change my json:  {  "idCustomer":"bb05ee35-0494-49e3-9e40-38d5dae10668",
  "name":"VenditaAbiti2",
"domain":"Commerce2"
 }  not work, now i have the same variables of my pojo class, i have to add also annotation(@SerializedName) ? now i not have

Comment: In my db i have this column: IdCustomer Name Domain Maybe is this the problem?

Comment: i have solved!!!! i have saved all my json in a string and then passed to fromJson String result=CommunityHome.getBody(req);
        System.out.println(result);
        Community community = g.fromJson(result, Community.class);

Comment: @FilomenaDelSorbo Perfect. hard work but you got it. The DB columns are no problem.

Comment: i have another problem with dodelete servlet method, when i send the id of my Community and i save in Community community = g.fromJson(json, Community.class); it calls the constructor of my class and overwrite my id with a new one...how i can solve this problem?